# Kubernetes Ingress difference of path/backend specification

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

What's the difference between these two specs in my ingress resource. Do they perform the same thing? When do I use which type?

```
spec:
  rules:
  - host: {{ .Values.Subdomain }}{{ .Values.Domain }}
    http:
      paths:
        - path: /api
          backend:
            serviceName: {{ .Values.ServiceName }}
            servicePort: 80
```

And:

```
spec:
  rules:
  - host: {{ .Values.Subdomain }}{{ .Values.Domain }}
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: {{ .Values.ServiceName }}
          servicePort: 80
        path: /api
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference. The `paths` field is a list of maps(dictionary), where each map consists of `path` and `backend` field. Within a map, the order of fields doesn't matter which is the case in your two templates.

Answer (score 0):

These two specifications are the same in [YAML](https://yaml.org/) - the order of items is not relevant.